# How to draw strings on Canvas using SharedPreference?

Tags: java, android, canvas

I have ArrayList of Strings and i want to save that list in Sharedprefrence i am able to do that and  i am also retrieving that strings but i want to know that how can i use that strings in canvas onDraw method and drawing on canvas.

Here I am Drawing Text on Screen and Saving it on ArrayLIst

```
if (text_c == 0 && c.getImage() == 4) {

        textsize = c.getTextsize();
        canvas.drawText(c.getEdittext(), startX, startY, mPaint);
        mPaint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
        c.setImage(0);


    }


for (EdtText l : editTexts) {


        mPaint.setTextSize(l.textsize);
        canvas.drawText(l.EdtText1, l.startX, l.stopY, mPaint);
        c.setstringDraw(editTexts.toString());
    }
```

Method for Saving Strings

```
public void saveString() {


    String sp=c.getStringDraw();



    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
    editor.putString("kEy", sp);
    editor.commit();

}
```

Method For Retrieving That String

```
public void openString(){


    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = sharedPrefs.getString("kEy", null);


}
```

Now , I want to retrieve Strings that saved in sharedpreference and want to draw in onDraw method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I add this lines to openString Method

```
public void openString(){


SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = sharedPrefs.getString("kEy", null);

   Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<EdtText>>() {
    }.getType();
    ArrayList<EdtText> arrayList = gson.fromJson(json, type);


    if (arrayList != null) {
        editTexts = arrayList;
    }
```

And Than In onDraw Method calling openString method

```
 if (text_save == 0) {

        openString();
        text_save++;
    }
```

That's  it....